# jQuery offset() or position()—Change an element's properties when close to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to have a nav bar set `position: fixed` to the top of my window, with links that smooth scroll to different sections.

I've got the smooth scrolling parts working just fine. Next, I want to change the colour of the navbar as it scrolls down the screen. I'd like things to switch/animate something like this:

When scrolled down to Section2 = Animate to a YELLOW Navbar
When scrolled down to Section3 = Animate YELLOW >  RED Navbar

I could easily achieve this effect via the click method (when the click on #section2, change the CSS), but how would I get it to change if users scrolled down the screen—without using the links in the nav bar?

Where I've gotten so far:     http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/4xkbs/2/

Thanks!

Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the scroll event, then in your event handler, get the offset for the sections to see if the y coordinate is at or above the nav list. Something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var bottom = $("#navcontainer").offset().top + $("#navcontainer").offset().height();
    if ($("#section3").offset().top <= bottom) {
        // Scrolled to or beyond section 3
    }
    else if ($("#section2").offset().top <= bottom) {
        // Scrolled to or beyond section 2, but not to section 3
    }
}
```

Binding to $(window).scroll in jsFiddle doesn't appear to work, so I haven't tested this code.